# Capturing time taken to load a screen on a react native app

Tags: react-native

I am implementing some events (firebase analytics purposes) such that I can extract the time taking to load a particular screen on my react native app. But I'm absolutely clueless, this is just to check the performance level of the app only.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Look into using the react-native-debugger. It has built in React DevTools. There is a profiler in there that can show you the render times and a lot more details for performance debugging.

Here are some more details about the profiler:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

Comment: To add to this, you may even be able to use the ActivityIndicator and display that when the data is loading and then display your UI when it is done. That could also give you an idea.